# CXR RS: Unable to send Date as a param in a POST call

Tags: java, rest, cxfrs

I want to receive a `Date` param using CXF.

The following code works in CXF 2.6.0, but not in CXF 3.0.0:

```
@POST
@Path("/getPlayers")
@Produces("application/json")
public List<Player> getPlayers(@FormParam("birthDate") Date birthDate) throws Exception;
```

If I declare `birthDate` as string this works.

What am I missing?

Comment: Added a description of what you want to achieve, and why you expected the code to work _before_ the actual code, so readers will be able to focus on the relevant parts of the code.